# How to extend QueryableFilterRepeater to override the filters shown?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, .net-4.0, dynamic-data

In previous versions of DynamicData you could override `GetFilteredColumns` method from `FilterRepeater` to manage which columns are used to generate filters.

But now `FilterRepeater` is obsolete, and his successor `QueryableFilterRepeater` don't have such method.

**There is any way to override the columns used for filtering with QueryableFilterRepeater?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After asking [Stephen Naughton](http://csharpbits.notaclue.net) for help (Thank you Stephen!). He told me there isn't a way to extend `QueryableFilterRepeater` for this purposes yet.

Anyway you could still using the `AutoGenerateFilter` property of the '[DisplayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd382116(v=VS.100).aspx)' to hide columns filters ; )